# Is there any way to get all the key/value pairs together from sc_client_db::offchain::LocalStorage?

Tags: offchain, offchain-storage

I can see we have the option to get the values by using their keys one by one using **get()**, but is there any way to get all the pairs together wrapped in an **iterator** so that we don't need to hit the **get()** multiple times?

Answer (score 6):

From the best of my knowledge there is no utility to do it, you are limited to `OffchainStorage` trait.
Technically, the offchain storage directly writes to the underlying db column (just prefixing the key).

So rocksdb user can iterate on that, but that is not a good solution as paritydb users cannot (it would need to switch paritydb to an ordered column which is not a light change).

Depending on your use case it may be possible to keep trace of order at a higher level (like storing a linked list or other), but that would be slow and a bit costy. (in some case it can be a best choice, when you need to handle concurrent access and add some mutex like protection with `compare_and_set`).

Can also think of rolling out your own backend, but then you cannot access it with the standard rpc (so probably no existing ui can access it).